# Invalid Write Size of 8 Valgrind

Tags: c, csv, valgrind

I'm writing a function to parse a .csv file and I am getting an error with valgrind. Specifically, it's this:

```
==5450== Invalid write of size 8
==5450==    at 0x404FA0: parse_exemplars (util.c:568)
==5450==    by 0x40508E: get_test_and_train_data (util.c:595)
==5450==    by 0x402737: setup (pony_gp.c:727)
==5450==    by 0x4027E5: main (pony_gp.c:761)
```

This is the code with the error lines indicated:

```
csv_reader *reader = init_csv(file_name, ',');

double **fitness_cases, *targets;
int num_columns = 122;
int num_lines = 121;

// leave space for NULL at end
fitness_cases = malloc(sizeof(double **) * num_lines);
for (int i = 0; i < num_lines; i++) {
    fitness_cases[i] = malloc(sizeof(double *));

    for (int k = 0; k < num_columns; k++) {
        fitness_cases[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (num_columns - 1));
    }
}

// leave space for NAN at end
targets = malloc(sizeof(double) * (num_lines));

csv_line *row;
int f_i = 0;
int t_i = 0;

while ((row = readline(reader))) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < num_columns; i++) {
        if (i == num_columns - 1) {
            targets[t_i++] = atof(row->content[i]);
        }
        else {
            fitness_cases[f_i][i] = atof(row->content[i]);
        }
    }

    fitness_cases[f_i][i-1] = (double)NAN; //<----- This is where it says the error is, line 568.
    f_i++;
}
```

Whenever I check the size of fitness_cases[f_i][i-1] I always get the same value as the size of (double)NAN, so my guess is it comes earlier in the function?

The link to the github page is (this function I'm asking about is not updated currently on the repo): https://github.com/dyingpie1/pony_gp_c

Comment: The allocation code makes no sense at all. What is the purpose of `for (int k...` cycle, whose body does not depend on `k` at all and just repeatedly overwrites the value of `fitness_cases[i]`, generating numerous memory leaks?

Comment: @Robbie: You seem to be trying to create a 2D array `fitness_cases`. It is **two**-dimensional. Yet you have **three** nested levels of memory allocation. Where did the third level come from? The third nested cycle `for (int k...` makes no sense whatsover, as I stated above.

Comment: Oh the allocation in the beginning is a typo, the I should be replaced with a k in the nested loop. I simplified the code before posting, but in the progress wrote in some errors.

Comment: @Robbie if you replace `i` with `k` in that nested loop it would make even less sense.

Comment: @Robbie: Replacing variables won't help anything here. You have three nested levels of memory allocation for a two-dimensional array. That is already broken.

Comment: But I'm building an array to an array of doubles. Don't you have to allocate the space for the double pointer, then allocate space to the pointer/array and  then allocate the space for the doubles in that inner array?

Comment: @Robbie "space for the double pointer" - already on stack, you only need to allocate array of `sizeof(double*)*num_rows`, and `num_rows` arrays of `sizeof(double)*num_columns`, or even use flat array for this simple case when column count is constant between rows.

Comment: You allocate space for arrays, not for pointers. The pointer points to the allocated space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fitness_cases[f_i][i-1] = (double)NAN;
```

Value of i-1 here will be `num_columns -1`  but as you have allocated the space as

```
fitness_cases[i] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (num_columns - 1));
```

Max index for second array-subscript could be one less ie num_columns - 2, otheriwise you are going out of bounds

e.g.

```
fitness_cases[i] = 3 * sizeof(double);
```

`fitness_cases[i][0]`,`fitness_cases[i][1]`,`fitness_cases[i][2]` are valid and `fitness_cases[i][3]` is out of bounds and will cause invalid write as indicated by valgrind